# Regarding seed specification in random number generator

Tags: r

I use `sample` function to perform some random sampling operation. Generally, random number generator is based on a seed value. How can I ensure that each R session or each sample invocation will use different seed value?

Comment: Does the Note section in `?Random` answer your question?

Comment: Why do you want a different seed for each call to `sample` repeated runs of `sample` without changing the seed will generate different pseudo-random samples - you don't need to explicitly set the seed each time to achieve that feat.

Comment: It is good to have different seed for each R session, but not each sample invocation.

Answer (score 4):

Whenever a seed for the RNG is first required, R generates one from the current time and the process ID for the running R session. The only (easy) way to set the seed is via `set.seed()`, so assuming that you don't save and restore the seed between sessions (which is possible and even a feature of reproducible research should you wish to store the seed) *and* don't call `set.seed()` with the same seed, you should get a different seed for each session.

To get a different seed used for each call to `sample`, you'd have to emulate what R does to some extent and set the seed to some new value prior to each call of `sample`. That is probably best arranged by a wrapper function which sets the seed to the new value **and** then calls `sample`.

For example:

```
Sample <- function(seed, ..., verbose = FALSE) {
  if(missing(seed))
    seed <- floor(as.numeric(Sys.time()) + Sys.getpid())
  if(verbose)
    writeLines(paste("Using seed:", seed))
  set.seed(seed)
  sample(...)
}

> Sample(x = 10)
 [1]  7  3  8  9 10  2  4  5  6  1
> Sample(x = 10, verbose = TRUE)
Using seed: 1365040429
 [1]  9  5  7 10  6  8  1  4  3  2
> Sample(x = 10, verbose = TRUE)
Using seed: 1365040431
 [1]  6  9  3  5  2  1 10  8  7  4
> Sample(x = 10, verbose = TRUE)
Using seed: 1365040432
 [1]  9  6  8  1  2 10  3  4  7  5
```

That's not perfect - if you call `Sample` too quickly (more than once per second) the same seed will get used for those runs called during that second.

More details are in `?Random`, which you should read.